# Can I make a partition on a drive different than the drive on which my windows resides for installing ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

So I want to install ubuntu on my laptop, and I've come across quite a few tutorials explaining how to do. I've my windows OS residing on disk C but there's not enough space available on disk C for shrinking. So I want to know if I can partition the disk D and install ubuntu on it. Also, can you give me a rough idea as to what size the partition is, in general for development purposes?

Comment: Can you use Virtual Machine for the development activity?

Comment: You can install it on an external drive also, If you want to. I would recommend at-least `20 GB` disk space but it would heavily depend on the work that you are going to do on the system.

Comment: Yeah, previously I was using VmWare workstation, but that was meant only for executing lab programmes at college as I had allocated only 20gb for that. Now I want to do away the VM, as I've switched to mainstream development.

Comment: You can shrink the partition from `gparted`, while in running the Ubuntu in try mode. But backup important data before attempting to make changes.

Comment: Many thanks! I used the windows tool to help do it. Apparently, the windows tool does it all for you.